# How to apply colour for mat-icon in angular by using the condition

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular8

[form field image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUTMi.png)->I need to add colour to check_circle mat-icon in angular and that icon is in the login form field

->After the user enters his email then it (check_circle) icon should change to green colour if he doesn't enter his email it should be in grey colour.

```
`[ngStyle]="changeColour()" And 

This is Ts file code 
[This is the screenshot of my form field][1]
changeColur(){
     if(this.loginForm.get('userName').value == 'admin@mcrb.com')
{
 return 'green'
    }
 else {
   return 'grey'
 }
}
```

`

->Here loginForm is the name of my form group, and userName is the name of my form-control name of that particular field and 'admin@mcrb.com' is the email that the user need to enter if he enters that email only the icon colour should change to green

->And changeColour() I have added this in my ngonInIt() also but it is not working anyone help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```js
   

    public changedColor: string;
   public loginForm: FormGroup;

   constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

   ngOnInit() {
    this.buildloginForm();
    this.loginForm.get('userName').valueChanges.subscribe((res) => 
    {
      console.log(res);
      if (res === 'admin') {
        this.changedColor = 'green';
      } else {
        this.changedColor = 'blue';
      }
    });
    }

    private buildloginForm() {
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      userName: [''],
    });
    }
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="loginForm">
<input type="text" formControlName="userName" class="primary- 
input mr-2" />
</form>

<p [ngStyle]="{ color: changedColor }">
 Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not working

Comment: @RevanthReddySince1998 remove the function and paste the code in `ngOnInit()`

Comment: this is my email revredddy@gmail.com mail me once explain in google meet please

Comment: let me create working example for you.

Comment: Is it done sir?

Comment: @RevanthReddySince1998 here is the example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-idrldt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @RevanthReddySince1998 don't forget to upvote.

Comment: HI SIR, I have another doubt will you send your email id lets meet once

Comment: @RevanthReddySince1998 email : `hi.myself.amansharma@gmail.com` email me only as of now i don't use meet